# Convert julian time into date in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert an array of Julian time into the standard Gregorian calendar. For that, I am using chron, which seems quite simple. The problem is that the origin does not fit with the beginning of the time. That means, I know the date starts at 12:00:00 in 23 May 2014 and end at 5th Sep 2014 at 7am. Then, if I use chron as the following:

```
#The first 50 values  

time <- dput(t[1:50])

structure(c(143.0208333, 143.0416667, 143.0625, 143.0833333, 
143.1041667, 143.125, 143.1458333, 143.1666667, 143.1875, 143.2083333, 
143.2291667, 143.25, 143.2708333, 143.2916667, 143.3125, 143.3333333, 
143.3541667, 143.375, 143.3958333, 143.4166667, 143.4375, 143.4583333, 
143.4791667, 143.5, 143.5208333, 143.5416667, 143.5625, 143.5833333, 
143.6041667, 143.625, 143.6458333, 143.6666667, 143.6875, 143.7083333, 
143.7291667, 143.75, 143.7708333, 143.7916667, 143.8125, 143.8333333, 
143.8541667, 143.875, 143.8958333, 143.9166667, 143.9375, 143.9583333, 
143.9791667, 144, 144.0208333, 144.0416667), .Dim = 50L)


#Convert into GCalen.
newtime <- chron(time, origin=c(month = 1, day = 1, year = 2014))
dates <- as.POSIXlt(newt, "GMT")
```

The dates start at:

```
"2014-05-24 00:29:59 GMT" "2014-05-24 01:00:00 GMT" "2014-05-24 01:30:00 GMT" "2014-05-24 01:59:59 GMT"....
```

Looking into the end of the dates, I would have the same problem, because it finishes at "2014-09-06 07:30:00 GMT", one day later ..so there is a substantial lapse that it needs to be fixed.
 is there any way to add in the origin the time?? hour:min:sg??

Comment: What you "know" seems to be wrong. If the origin is "00:00:00" xxx.020833 can't be "12:00:00". xxx.5 would be.

Comment: Oh, sorry , the data is supposed to start 23th of May 0 am until 5th of September 2014 7 am..(the time dimension has been created from 1January of 2014). Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Don't forget about the three little words: "daylight savings time". Or about Jan-01 being day-0.

Comment: OK, thanks! it was a pretty simple!! I totally forgot it!..thank you!